# fast way to generate a combination of strings

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, equation

we're going to generate all possible math equations today.

Given a a syntax like this: `[1,0][+,-][2,3]` which means we need all strings with 1 or 0 as first character, + or - as second character, and 2 or 3 as third character.

So that's 8 possible combinations

```
1+2
1+3
1-2
1-3
0+2
0+3
0-2
0-3
```

My approach would work, but it would get pretty slow for slightly large values. I parse the above syntax and create an array of possible values for each token, and place that in an array.

```
equation_set = []; 
tokens = [['1','0'],['+','-'],['2','3']]
// Initialize empty equation_set
token = tokens.pop();
foreach symbol in tokens
question_set.add(symbol)

// We now have a question_set = ['1','0']
// and tokens = [['+','-']['2','3']]
//
// Now we need to fill out the rest of the possible equations
foreach token in tokens
    new_question_set = []
    foreach symbol in token
        foreach question in question_set
            new_question_set.add(question + symbol)
    question_set = new_question_set
```

I believe that should give me the results I want, but all those foreach's make me rather nervous. I just now figured out this algorithm, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious. We're messing with combinatorics, so I won't be surprised if it's extremely slow, but it feels like this isn't anything special.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you need to generate them all at once? i.e, do you need to be able to have a collection containing all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create all combinations, you will have to perform nested loops of some sort.

Make sure your iterations are performed in [row major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (assuming your language stores your collection in row major order, which most but not all do).  Failing to do so can have quite a large impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

first off, i wouldn't hard-code your answer to only have 3 layers like that.  Instead, I'd suggest using recursion.

If the recursion gets too hairy and you have stack overflows than you can use dynamic programming.

if you don't know what dynamic programming is, than i doubt that you'll be required to use  it for this problem.

As far as the efficiency goes, you are going to have exponential time complexity no matter what.  this is unavoidable due to the fact that you also have an exponentially large number of outputs.

Answer (score 0):

For large cases the easy-to-write recursive approach may cause problems more quickly than using counters for processing the subsets (token) and the characters therein (symbol).

For a tokensize 3 (rather than 2, as in your case) and 15 tokens (rather than 3), the code below generated the required list of resultstrings (3**15 = 14.348,907 in total) in about 10 seconds on my not-so-new PC.

If that suits you, have a try with something like (vb: I quickly wrote it in an existing project I'm working on):

```
' decompose input
Dim allSubSets As New List(Of List(Of Char))
Dim subSet As List(Of Char) = Nothing

For Each c As Char In inputLine

  Select Case c
    Case "["c
      subSet = New List(Of Char)
    Case "]"c
      allSubSets.Add(subSet)
    Case ","c
      ' just skip
    Case Else
      subSet.Add(c)
  End Select

Next

Dim numberOfSubSets As Integer = allSubSets.Count
Dim subSetLength As Integer = allSubSets(0).Count

Dim allResults As New List(Of String)
Dim caseArray(numberOfSubSets - 1) As Char

' 1st / initialize
Dim setIndex As Integer

Dim charIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
For setIndex = 0 To numberOfSubSets - 1
  caseArray(setIndex) = allSubSets(setIndex)(0)
  charIndexes.Add(0)
Next
Dim caseResult As New String(caseArray)
allResults.Add(caseResult)
Dim resultCount As Long = 1

' current position
setIndex = numberOfSubSets - 1

' do the others
Do
  ' if the current subSet is exhausted, track back (iteratively)
  While (setIndex >= 0) AndAlso (charIndexes(setIndex) = subSetLength - 1)
    ' and restart the subset we're going the re-access later on
    charIndexes(setIndex) = 0
    setIndex -= 1
  End While

  ' exit if we're done
  If setIndex = -1 Then
    Exit Do
  End If

  ' increase counter in the current subset
  charIndexes(setIndex) += 1

  ' fill the (remainder of the) case
  While setIndex < numberOfSubSets
    caseArray(setIndex) = allSubSets(setIndex)(charIndexes(setIndex))
    setIndex += 1
  End While
  ' correct the last increment
  setIndex -= 1

  ' store result
  caseResult = New String(caseArray)
  allResults.Add(caseResult)
  resultCount += 1

Loop
```

where "inputLine" is in the format you specified.
Furthermore, if your tokens differ in size, you will have to adapt the code, such that the right toke-size is used; I assumed for now they would all be equal in length.

good luck!